# Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin

I have a very small team. Some of which are using Mac and some are using Windows. We are only supporting iOS and Android. Can some of them use Xamarin Studio where as some use VS on the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Xamarin projects use the Visual Studio `.sln` format, so solutions are interchangeable between Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio regardless of which IDE you start with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use both, all you need is setup common git repo and you can sync through remote git either with GitHub or BitBucket. However on Windows, Xamarin Studio is no longer available.